# Check if a list contains items in other list

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have two lists.Say

```
list1 ="a,b,c";
list2="d,a,c";
```

How to check if list1 contains items in list2 .I mean how to check if list2  has a

Comment: Those aren't lists - they're strings. Do you *actually* have strings, or something like `List<string>`?

Comment: <nitpicking> Well, traditionally, isn't string === char[] </nitpicking>

Comment: @SWeko, (nitpicking too...) not in the .net world and arrays are not lists either

Answer (score 5):

Those are strings, not lists...

However you can do (UPDATE as per comments):

```
List<string> MyIntersectionList = 
list1.Split ( ',' )
.Intersect (list2.Split ( ',' ))
.ToList();
```

As a result `MyIntersectionList` contains all elements that are in both strings...

EDIT - IF you really have Lists then the above gets easier:

```
List<string> MyIntersectionList = list1.Intersect (list2).ToList();
```

Comment: `list1.Split(',')` should be sufficient, no need for `new char[] { ... }`

Comment: And the `AsEnumerable()` is also unnecessary

Comment: And the final ToList is 'probably' also unnecessary if you just want to loop through the duplicates

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your lists are actually comma separated values in a string

You could use the following logic which performance will be OK even if you have many elements:

```
var list2Members = new HashSet<string>(list2.Split(','));
bool list1ItemsInList2 = list1.Split(',').All(item => list2Members.Contains(item));
```

Comment: +1 great answer, though be aware that for small lists the overhead of building the `HashSet` may outweigh its ability to do fast look-ups.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker, agreed, if there are few elements, he could use list1Members.All(item => list2Members.Contains(item))        in which listNMembers is the direct result of Split